# Script en VB para macro en excel que seleccione ID que posee multiples resultados y los muestre en una lista desplegable

Tags: excel, script, vb

Estoy elaborando un formulario

el usuario debe ser capaz de seleccionar de una lista desplegable un ID, el tema es que tengo muchas líneas con el mismo ID porque están segmentadas por tramos de la siguiente manera

ID   ID Tramo de linea
234  2341
234  2345
234  3456
235  3457
235  4567
236  1234
236  5678
236  9012
236  9801

entonces los Id se repiten porque es el id de la linea completa y el tramo es un id unico porque es el id de los segmentos de esa linea,
necesito que en un formulario el usuario puede elegir el ID de la linea y le aparezcan en otra celdas como una lista desplegable todas las opciones de tramo de linea asociadas a ese ID que seleccionaron.

Sub MostrarTramosAsociados()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lineaSeleccionada As Variant
Dim tramos As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

```
' Especifica el nombre de la hoja donde están los datos
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulario")

' Obtiene el ID de línea seleccionado por el usuario
lineaSeleccionada = ws.Range("D15").Value

' Inicializa la cadena de tramos
tramos = ""

' Encuentra la última fila con datos en la columna de IDs de tramos
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

' Recorre los datos para buscar IDs de tramos asociados a la línea seleccionada
For i = 2 To lastRow ' Empieza desde la fila 2 para omitir encabezados
    If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = lineaSeleccionada Then
        If tramos = "" Then
            tramos = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
        Else
            tramos = tramos & ", " & ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
        End If
    End If
Next i

' Muestra los IDs de tramos asociados en la celda C1 y siguientes
ws.Range("C1").Value = tramos
```

End Sub

muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Y lo que has intentado va también en la pregunta, de este modo, incrementas las chances de obtener alguna respuesta. Saludos :)

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)